# Is it possible to call an function nested in another function (PowerShell)?

Tags: powershell, function, class

I'm very used to Python where functions can be put in classes and called separately.

However, now I have to code something in PowerShell and I can't find a way if something similar would be possible here.

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
function a {
    Write-Host "a"

    function a_1() { Write-Host "a_1" }

    function a_2() { Write-Host "a_2" }
    
}

a      # Works
a.a_1  # Doesn't works
a_2    # Doesn't works
```

Comment: Only if the inner function have a scope modifier, i.e.: `function script:a_1() { ... }` or `function global:a_2() { ... }`

Comment: You may be looking for [PowerShell modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-7.2); they don't let you _nest_ functions this way, but they do allow grouping functions together

Comment: This is a scoping issue - the functions `a_1` and `a_2` are defined in the scope of `a`, and thus cease to exist once the function returns. You can persist them in the calling scope by using the `.` dot-source invocation operator: `. a; a_1; a_2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell (5 and above) does have support for classes, (see [about_Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2)) and class methods can be static.

So for example:

```
class a {
    a() {
        Write-Host "a"
    }
    static [void]a_1()
    {
        Write-Host "a_1"
    }
    static [void]a_2()
    {
        Write-Host "a_2"
    }
}

[a]$a = [a]::new()
[a]::a_1()
[a]::a_2()
```

Output:

```
a
a_1
a_2
```

Answer (score 1):

> Only if the inner function have a scope modifier, i.e.: function script:a_1() { ... } or function global:a_2() { ... } –
> [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)

Thanks! This seems close enough to what I'm searching for, in combination with creative naming of the functions this makes it possible to get something I'm used to.

Solution for me:

```
function a {
    Write-Host "a"

    function script:a.a_1() { Write-Host "a_1" }

    function script:a.a_2() { Write-Host "a_2" }
    
}

a       # Call this so the functions get loaded
a.a_1   # Creative naming so it acts like I need it
a.a_2
```

Comment: Actually what Mathias suggested is much more elegant than modifying the inner function's scope.